# Can I extend multiple integer types at once to be initializable from an array of bytes?

Tags: swift

Using Swift 4, is there any way to compress these byte array initializers down?  I hate having to create the call in each extension. Wishing there were a way to make this a single init method.

```
private func fromByteArray<T>(bytes: [UInt8]) -> T where T : UnsignedInteger {
    return bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: T.self, capacity: 1) {
            $0
        }
    }.pointee
}

extension UInt16 {
    init(bytes: [UInt8]) {
        self.init(bigEndian: fromByteArray(bytes: bytes))
    }
}

extension UInt32 {
    init(bytes: [UInt8]) {
        self.init(bigEndian: fromByteArray(bytes: bytes))
    }
}

extension UInt64 {
    init(bytes: [UInt8]) {
        self.init(bigEndian: fromByteArray(bytes: bytes))
    }
}
```

Comment: extend `UnsignedInteger`.

Comment: or `FixedWidthInteger` if you also want to include signed integer types. Although note that your `fromByteArray` implementation currently exhibits *undefined behaviour*, as you're escaping the pointer argument from the closure passed to `withMemoryRebound` – instead, say `bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: T.self, capacity: 1) { $0.pointee } }` (although note this doesn't perform any range checking to make sure the buffer is long enough; really it ought to do that, otherwise you're back in UB-land if the buffer is too short).

Comment: Also, you may want to consider using `Data` instead of `[UInt8]` – it has a dedicated method for getting a pointer to its (possibly reinterpreted) contents: `withUnsafeBytes(_:)`.

Comment: @Alexander That doesn't address the question nor does it work because UnsignedInteger doesn't have the bigEndian initializer.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for pointing out that undefined behavior!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to one-up everybody by giving you one that not only collapses everything into one initializer in one extension, but also takes any sequence of `UInt8` (including `Data`, `DispatchData`, `Array`, `ContiguousArray`, or anything else) and doesn't rely on Foundation *and* lets you choose your endianness:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    init<Bytes: Sequence>(bytes: Bytes, littleEndian: Bool = false) where Bytes.Element == UInt8 {
        var s: Self = 0

        let width = Self.bitWidth / 8

        for (i, byte) in bytes.enumerated() where i < width {
            let shiftAmount = (littleEndian ? i : (width - 1 - i)) * 8

            s |= (Self(truncatingIfNeeded: byte) << shiftAmount)
        }

        self = s
    }
}
```

Comment: "self = s" this will yield incorrect on little endian platforms. Use `self.init(bigEndian: s)` instead

Comment: @Alexander No it won't. `s` is built using the bit-shifting operator, not reinterpreted pointers, so it will work independently of endianness (well, other than the endianness of the source data, but you know what I mean).

Comment: Note that `Self(byte)` can overflow if `Self` is `Int8`. I don’t have a Swift environment to hand, but I believe `Self(truncatingIfNeeded: byte)` should fix that.

Comment: @Hamish Fair point, although if you'd pass an array of bytes to an initializer for `Int8`... I just gotta ask why ;-)

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Yeah probably not an actual issue for direct usage, though it could have bitten you if you built more generic code on top of this :)

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Is there a way to tell this the starting byte, instead of 0?  e.g. I might have bytes as an array of 1000 items and I want to pull starting at by 832

Comment: @Gargoyle Just pass `array[(array.startIndex + 832)...]` (note that `array[832...]` will work too for an array, but that will fail for certain other types in unexpected ways, so it's good to get into the habit of using `startIndex`).